# Execute JavaScript on AJAX Panel Load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, templates

I want to run a JavaScript function to initialize some controls.

My problem is that the controls are on a Telerik control's form template that is displayed using AJAX.

Is there a way to specify the JavaScript function executes whenever this template is displayed?

Comment: Have you tried to use the ajax call back method? what is happening then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean. I'm an experienced developer but haven't worked a whole lot with AJAX. Which callback exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is no. While there are some convoluted ways to trigger JavaScript on an AJAX postback, trying them stopped the Telerik controls from working. I guess they rely on that technique already. Anyway, I've moved on to approach the problem from a different angle.